# Rails console can find model instances but app doesn't. How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something unusual is happening with my app. I have a model called User and I made one instance from the Rails console. I can get it from the console, but not from the app.

Any hint on what may cause this behaviour?

If I run `User.count` in console I get 1, in app I get 0.

Running `Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]` gives the same result in console and app: `{"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/development.sqlite3"}`

(Running Ruby 2.6.0 and Rails 5.2.3)

I'm starting to think that Rails is making a fool of me

Edit. My controller method:

```
def index
  puts "DB CONF: #{Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]}"
  puts "USER COUNT: #{User.count}" #prints 0 to console
  render plain: "#{User.count}" #prints 0 on page
end
```

Code in console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
2.6.0 :001 > User.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
 => 1
```

Comment: There are a myriad of reasons this might happen. It might help to see the controller action to prove you're calling it and logging it correctly.

Comment: just confirm both are pointing to the same database? restart app server

Comment: @VeridianDynamics see edited.

Comment: @SachinR Which is the best way to check this? Restarted countless times.

Comment: The easiest way to check is to show us your `environment/*.rb` files and your  `database.yml` file. To me, it looks like it should say "1" but it's pretty clear you're not hooked up to the same DB. Are you consoling in the right app?

Comment: console is Loading "development" environment (Rails 5.2.3) can you confirm app's is also the same and not production

Comment: @SachinR => Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development

Comment: @VeridianDynamics you can read the 2 files here https://hastebin.com/oxopohojaf.rb

Comment: Okay, perfect! This proves that you are not correctly connecting to the same database. You should test with these commands `RAILS_ENV=development rails s -b localhost` and `RAILS_ENV=development rails c`. That will force rails to load the same environment "development". Also, make sure you're doing this in the same folder!

Comment: @VeridianDynamics I'm confused... From where did you get that info? Also: tried your code, but I'm still getting the same results... Regarding the folder I'm using the same terminal window without CDing between the commands, you know, just to be sure 

Comment: I somehow solved this. I have no idea how. I'm so sorry for waisting your time guys, I feel so stoopid right now... Thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: I think it's highly likely that you were somehow connecting to the wrong DB. Why? We **know** your `User` model was loading. Therefore, you were at least preforming this in a Rails app with a `User` model. You environment was reporting the same. therefore, we **know** you were loading the `development` DB for that app. Lastly, your DB was persisting across restarts. The console always had that same `1` user which means *its* DB never dropped. So, it **must** be that you were in a valid DB with a `User` model each time but they were not the same DB.

Comment: @VeridianDynamics 100% agree with you, still don't know how